# Host multiple sites on same IP/port in IIS

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, subdomain

I'm trying to get a second site running from IIS with the same IP/port combination as my "Default Web Site". I understand that I *should* be able to do this using the binding settings in IIS and then pointing the new host name to the correct IP in the DNS settings.

My default site is configured to use the subdomain apps.mysite.com and the second site will be employee.mysite.com. In IIS, I created a binding entry on the new site for apps.mysite.com on port `8080` for testing purposes and another for employee.mysite.com on port `80` which will be the live version:

[image: site bindings]

**If I go to http://apps.mysite.com:8080 in a browser, it successfully routes to my new site. My problem is that http://employee.mysite.com does not.**

I have to think this is a DNS issue, right? A separate team has control over our DNS so I can't confirm for certain what they did to point the new subdomain to the web server but I think they have a `CNAME` record that points to apps.mysite.com. Is that correct or do we need an `A` record instead that points directly to the IP?

Comment: What’s the exact error you get when you try the employee sub domain? You can verify DNS by pinging the names - they should both resolve to an IP on your IIS server. You can also use nslookup for this.

Comment: All such sites can be hosted at port 80, but you must give the right site bindings. Run a few reports when you change IIS settings till everything works as you wanted, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#the-built-in-binding-diagnostics

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the team in charge of creating the DNS record had typo'd. Nothing was wrong with my bindings.